# IBM Worklight 6.1 - How to display a prompt dialog?

Tags: javascript, android, ibm-mobilefirst

It was able to display a prompt box  in common resources ("preview as common resources"), but it is not working in the Android Emualtor.

What is the reason?

Comment: if my answer helped resolve your problem, please mark as answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried [using Cordova's navigator.prompt](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.1.0/cordova_notification_notification.md.html#notification.prompt)?

For example, in common\main.js:

```
function wlCommonInit() {
    navigator.notification.prompt(
        'Please enter your name',  // message
        onPrompt,                  // callback to invoke
        'Registration',            // title
        ['Ok','Exit'],             // buttonLabels
        'Jane Doe'                 // defaultText
    );
}

function onPrompt() {
    alert("prompted");
}
```

I tested this in iOS, but it will work in Android as well.

When previewing your application, use some stub or "regular" JS implementation, but for the mobile environments, use Cordova's.

[image]