# IBM Worklight 6.2 - adding text input in WL.SimpleDialog

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-runtime

I know by adding  `WL.SimpleDialog.show` i can show a native style dialog/alert box with buttons. But is it possible to show the same with a **textbox** and yes and no buttons.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot achieve that with `WL.SimpleDialog`. However, if by "textbox" you mean a dialog with an input field in it, better known as a Prompt, then you could follow my example in the following question: [IBM Worklight 6.1 - How to display a prompt dialog?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22837521/ibm-worklight-6-1-how-to-display-a-prompt-dialog/)

The code in your case could be like this:

```
navigator.notification.prompt(
        'Replace me',  // message
        onPrompt,                  // callback to invoke
        'myPrompt',            // title
        ['Yes','No'],             // buttonLabels
        'My default text'                 // defaultText
    );
}

function onPrompt() {
    alert("prompted");
}
```